# Does anyone have an example of how to get the names of files into a dropdown on an ASP.NET Core MVC Razor page?

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOLAs.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1Pjy.png)

This is being used in an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app.

Here is some code for doing it manually but I need to read the folder file names and have them populate the dropdown. I am new to this so any help is appreciated.

```
 <dd class="col-sm-10">
     <select name="PHOTO1" id="PHOTO1" class="form-control">
         <option value="USA">USA</option>
         <option value="UK">UK</option>
         <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
         <option value="France">France</option>
     </select>
     <span asp-validation-for="PHOTO1" class="text-danger"></span>
</dd>
```

Comment: `foreach( FileInfo fi in new DirecotryInfo( @"path-to/user-images/" ).GetFiles( "*.gif" ) ) {`

Comment: Thanks for your response, however I am new to this. Can you elaborate a little more on the implementation?

Comment: To clarify, are you saying that you're unfamiliar with a `foreach` statement? and/or the `FileInfo` and `DirectoryInfo` classes?

Comment: OK so this produces a list but it is showing the full path. Any suggestions on how to show only the file names and trim the path out?  <select name="PHOTO1" id="PHOTO1" class="form-control">
     @foreach (FileInfo fi in new DirectoryInfo(@"wwwroot/user_images/").GetFiles())
     {
         <option value="fi">@fi</option>
     }
 </select>

Comment: Hint: `Url.Content`, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.iurlhelper.content?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 0):

In instances where you're reading files from the file system, I recommend that you inject the [IWebHostEnvironment interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iwebhostenvironment?view=aspnetcore-6.0), and then use the `WebRootPath` property to resolve the absolute file path for the the `wwwroot` folder, which can then be used to get subfiles and subfolders such as your `user_images` folder:

```
@inject IWebHostEnvironment env;

<select name="PHOTO1" id="PHOTO1" class="form-control">
    @{
        var userImagesDirName = "user_images";
        var userImagesPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(env.WebRootPath, userImagesDirName);
        var userImagesDir = new DirectoryInfo(userImagesPath);
        var userImagesFiles = userImagesDir.GetFiles();
    }
    @foreach (FileInfo file in userImagesFiles) {
        @* Then use the @Url.Content helper to resolve a HTTP link to the file path *@
        <option value="@Url.Content($"~/{userImagesDirName}/{file.Name}")">
            @file.Name
        </option>
    }
</select>
```

To get just the name of the file (without the path), use `@file.Name`. With the full path it's `@file.FullName`.

To get a relative HTTP-link to the file path, use `@Url.Content($"~/{userImagesDirName}/{file.Name}")`.

EDIT: Also it looks like you're trying to associate country names/values with images, and in that case I would suggest storing that data in a database, including the filename of the image.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, thank you! The part you saw with the country names was not relevant to this question. It was just an artifact of some things I had researched.

Comment: @Chasmcc40 You're welcome. Also if I answered your question, could you mark my answer as accepted? https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers It makes it easier to identify when a correct answer has been given to a SO question.